# Updating oracle records that starts with special char

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have below table dim_ethernet which has a column 5G_ON_AIR_DT
. I have to update its value from programming so I have written syntax in below style .

I got an error while running the code.
Does any one know how to write this code properly.

```
update ORA.dim_ethernet 
   set "5G_ON_AIR_DT" =: 5G_ON_AIR_DT  
 WHERE SITE_DWKEY =: SITE_DWKEY;
```

Comment: It is very useful to post the error so we're not guessing.  `=:` is never valid syntax, you'd want `=` in both the `set` clause and in the `where` clause.  Both the `set` and `where` are apparently trying to reference the same columns which seems unlikely to be what you want.  The second reference to `5G_ON_AIR_DT` is missing the double quotes.  I'm not sure which of these errors is causing whatever error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are very new to Oracle world. Couple of things that are worth considering.

Your Query:

```
update ORA.dim_ethernet 
   set "5G_ON_AIR_DT" =: 5G_ON_AIR_DT  
 WHERE SITE_DWKEY =: SITE_DWKEY;
```

Points:

1. =: makes no sense as it is not valid in either SQL or PLSQL.
2. := is an assignment operator in PLSQL.
3. = is assignment operator in SQL
4. PLSQL and SQL are two different engines but work together flawlessly giving an impression that they are one and the same. But in fact, they are not.
5. :some_val acts as a bind variable.
6. Using "column_name" is bad. Objects in Oracle are not case sensitive and if you put any object name inside double quotes, then it becomes case sensitive. There is no need to make your column name case sensitive.

That said, post the sample data and expected output. You will receive the best replies on the forum to handle what you are doing.

Comment: #6 is generally true but apparently false in this case.  `"column_name"` is apparently required here because the column name was created with a number as the first character meaning that it is not a valid Oracle identifier.  You can only do that if you double-quote the column name.

Comment: @JustinCave, completely agree with you on this. Here is what I think, why are we creating the column name with a number in the starting position which simply gets rejected by Oracle. Meaning don't you think we can improve there ? So, my point was we should create objects in oracle that are generally done in a recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

You have an identifier `5G_ON_AIR_DT`.

From the [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) documentation:

> 6. Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any character.

Since your identifier does not begin with an alphabetic character it cannot be used as a non-quoted identifier and always must be used with quotes.

You also have syntax errors with the `=:` and should be using `=` instead.

This would give you the query:

```sql
UPDATE ORA.dim_ethernet 
SET    "5G_ON_AIR_DT" = "5G_ON_AIR_DT"
WHERE  SITE_DWKEY = SITE_DWKEY;
```

*(Note: this statement will update the rows where `SITE_DWKEY` is not `NULL` and modify the `5G_ON_AIR_DT` column to be its current value; so appears to be a pointless operation but would now be syntactically valid.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=af512a66780fe7d5a8420ad7579207f6)*